# Calling Javascript Variable Value In PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I found that the coding below doesn’t work. What should I do to make it work? "$some" any idea ?

```
<?php 
   $some = $_GET['secondes']; 
   echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            setTimeout('document.custSearch.submit()',  $some);   
         </script>";
?>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    beforeload = (new Date()).getTime();
    function pageloadingtime()
    {
        afterload = (new Date()).getTime();
        secondes = (afterload - beforeload);
        document.getElementById("loadingtime").innerHTML = "<font color='red'> Page Load took "    + secondes + " sec</font>";
    }
    window.onload = pageloadingtime;
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: What does it not do that it should? What does it do that it shouldn't?

Comment: what is `afterload-beforeload`?

Comment: Your JS is broken. you never define `afterload` or `beforeload`

Comment: @LeeTaylor, i want the page auto submit directly once the page have been reload.so i want count the loading time of this page but $some cannot work

Comment: @Cfreak, im still new in stackoverflow. thank you.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    beforeload = (new Date()).getTime();
    function pageloadingtime()
    {
    afterload = (new Date()).getTime();
    secondes = (afterload - beforeload);
    document.getElementById("loadingtime").innerHTML = "<font    color='red'> Page Load took " + secondes + " sec</font>";
    }
 
    window.onload = pageloadingtime;</script>

Comment: @MarcB, I have define both of it , sorry that i didnt make it clear .

Comment: I found that this can work        ".json_encode($some_complex_array).";
Thank everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you haven't defined the `afterload` and `beforeload` variables. This is my first observation, the second one is that I'm agains mixing up PHP code and Javascript code for several reasons. The most obvious of them is that PHP is a server side language, interpreted on the server and the JS runs on the client after the PHP has already been executed.

If you really want to mix them up you need to be extra careful, and I really don't think that it is worth. Also, PHP is usually used to implement business logic, data access and so on, so my suggestion is that you keep it away from your presentation, using in the HTML just the things you really can't go on without: those things you've tried to refactor the most you could, and still you didn't find a better way to deal with them.

If you want a more complete answer regarding your problem, I think you should post more context: what are you trying to accomplish? Is there any more code you have to show?

Comment: Hi,thank for your suggestion. but Im just learn PHP and JS. And im still new in programming. If using other language than i may spent some time. Indeed, I do appreciate your suggestion